# Chomsky Hierarchy doesn't make sense to me.

Tags: formal-languages

[Wiki Article: Chomsky Hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)

In this containment hierarchy regular languages are a subset of context-sensitive languages.  But let $\sum$ be the alphabet we're using.  Then $\sum^*$ is a regular language that contains all languages on $\sum$.  So it seems to me that we should think of regular languages as the more broad languages and context-sensitive languages as more specific.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: The containment hierarchy is about containment of one *class* of languages within another class, but your $\Sigma^*$ observation is about containment of one *language* within another language.

Comment: $\Sigma^*$ is also a context-free language.  In fact every regular language is context-free.  So the context-free languages are a more general class than the regular languages.  (Brian's answer gives more detail.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let an alphabet $\Sigma$ be given, and define $\Sigma^*$ in the usual way. Now let $\mathscr{L}=\wp(\Sigma^*)$, the collection of all subsets of $\Sigma^*$; the members of $\mathscr{L}$ are the languages over the alphabet $\Sigma$. (In other words, the languages over $\Sigma$ are precisely the subsets of $\Sigma^*$.) The Chomsky hierarchy distinguishes certain subfamilies of $\mathscr{L}$:

$$\begin{align*}
\mathscr{L}_0&=\{L\in\mathscr{L}:\text{some formal grammar over }\Sigma\text{ generates }L\}\\
\mathscr{L}_1&=\{L\in\mathscr{L}:\text{some context-sensitive grammar over }\Sigma\text{ generates }L\}\\
\mathscr{L}_2&=\{L\in\mathscr{L}:\text{some context-free grammar over }\Sigma\text{ generates }L\}\\
\mathscr{L}_3&=\{L\in\mathscr{L}:\text{some regular grammar over }\Sigma\text{ generates }L\}
\end{align*}$$

These are all subfamilies of $\mathscr{L}$: they are **collections** of languages, and it can be shown that $$\mathscr{L}_3\subsetneq\mathscr{L}_2\subsetneq\mathscr{L}_1\subsetneq\mathscr{L}_0\subsetneq\mathscr{L}$$ (provided that $|\Sigma|\ge 2$).

$\Sigma^*$, on the other hand, is **not** a collection of languages: it’s a single language that happens to belong to $\mathscr{L}_3$. It’s perfectly true that every $L\in\mathscr{L}$ is a subset of $\Sigma^*$, but the class $\mathscr{L}_3$ of regular languages is **not** closed under taking subsets: it’s entirely possible for a regular language to have a non-regular language as a subset. In particular, the fact that every language over $\Sigma$ is a subset of the regular language $\Sigma^*$ says nothing at all about the inclusiveness of the class $\mathscr{L}_3$ of regular languages. It simply happens to be the case that the most restrictive **class** of languages in the hierarchy turns out to contain the most inclusive single **language**.